# The function has several arguments. However, do not pass all parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From select I choose the value `completed`,`uncompleted` or `inprogress`. In the `handleStatus` function, I call the`getDetail` function and passes it the value `status = e.target.value`. However, in the `getDetail` function in`console.log (status)`return me`undefined`

Code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kk4yv8

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      status: ''
    }
  }

    handleStatus = (e) => {
        this.setState({
                status: e.target.value
        })

        this.getDetail(status = e.target.value)
    }

    getDetail = (query, status) => {
        console.log(status)
    }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <select
            value={this.state.status}
            onChange={(e) => this.handleStatus(e)}
        >
            <option value="completed">completed</option>
            <option value="uncompleted">uncompleted</option>
            <option value="inprogress">inprogress</option>
        </select>   
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: What exactly is your intent with the line `this.getDetail(status = e.target.value)`?

Comment: @CollinD in `this.getDetails` I have two arguments query and status. I pass in this situation only status. I want to assign to status value e.target.value

Comment: Sounds like Nicholas' answer has you covered perfectly then! Another option if you need optional unordered arguments would be to use an options object, `this.getDetail({ status: e.target.value });`

Comment: @CollinD good idea on the options object; i've incorporated that into my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
this.getDetail(status = e.target.value)
```

javascript does not have named arguments. This code means "assign `e.target.value` to the variable `status`, and then pass that in as the first parameter. Inside of getDetail, that first parameter is assigned to the local variable `query`. No second parameter was passed in, so inside getDetail, the second parameter is undefined. That second parameter may be referred to as `status` locally, but this is unrelated to what's going on outside the function.

If you want to pass e.target.value in as the status, you need to put it as the second parameter:

```
this.getDetail(undefined, e.target.value);
```

For this reason, it's common to put variables that are optional towards the end of the argument list, so you can simply omit them, rather then filling in an explicit undefined.

Another option if you have a large set of arguments to pass in is to use a single argument, which is an object. The code inside the function can check if properties exist on that object, and code calling the function can omit or include properties on the object at will. For example:

```
const example = (options) {
  if (options.status) {
    // whatever
  }
  if (options.query) {
    // whatever
  }
}

// To be used like:

example({ query: 'foo', status: 'complete' });
example({ status: 'incomplete' });
example({ query: 'bar' });
```